# How to handle SIGINT in a program using CRT unit?

Tags: linux, freepascal, lazarus

I have a console application (`program`) which uses the *CRT* unit. Under Linux, when I press `CTRL+C`, nothing happens. However, I want to handle this `SIGINT` signal as one would expect (by quitting the program immediately). I found some notice that using `CRT` re-defines STDIN and STDOUT stuff, so that the normal SIG handlers don't work. Currently, I tried `fpSignal(SIGINT, SignalHandler(@DoSig));`, but still pressing `CTRL+C` doesn't do anything. When I send a SIGINT to the process manually (via *htop*), the handler kicks in. But not with CTRL+C.
Not using `CRT` unit is not an option, unfortunately.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What do you call the CRT unit? Are you talking about the screen? Some terminal emulator under X11? Most PCs have an LCD screen these days...

Comment: And you should show your source code to get help. Did you read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ & http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: by "CRT Unit" I mean the freepascal unit CRT: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that CRT unit will redirect standard input/output handles, so you have to check for SIGINT "by hand", signal handler will not work.
You should check for key pressed with KeyPressed function and then check with ReadKey if SIGINT (eg: Ctrl-C) has been sent.